# Why does the controller path have to be defined in both the main single view app and the partial view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a single page application, I have to define the controller path at both places in the main index page and in partial view.

If I remove this from the partial view it isn't rendered correctly.

Why do I have to do it like this?

Comment: Can you show me an example what you meant?

Comment: problem is with :"app/js/sessionapp.js"

Comment: Please post the required js file code also

Comment: What do you mean by required js.I am not getting please tell me

Comment: Well can you show us what have you put your routing/view in the js files? Also can you edit the question with code, instead of commenting them.

Comment: i resolve the js at route. its working now.